# What target heart rate or power do people use when commuting by bike

Tags: power, heart-rate

Biking to work is good exercise. It can make it easier to meet our exercise needs.

When commuting by bike, what heart rate or power zones do people usually use?
What's a recommended target? Should we try to get to work as fast as possible or at a more relaxed pace? Do the commuters decide it based on feel?

Which days should we do sprinting? Should we have similar schedules every week?

An example of a schedule with the zones can be helpful.

Let's say you work full time and you want to break the plateau. You want the kind of fitness improvements that make you bike to work faster and improve race times.

Update Dec 20
Possible fitness goals: Faster commuting times, faster cruising speeds, 30 km/h feels easy, faster sprints to decrease missing green lights, being able to outrun wolves and bears. Getting to work faster on a bike means less need for driving to work or e-bikes!

If intervals are done, does that mean the next day must be zone 1 to be fully recovered to train hard enough for your next interval session? Is the fat burning zone good enough?

Comment: Positive integers is a good target.

Comment: Sorry, but this is much too broad for a meaningful question. The typical heart value can be just about anything the heart is capable of, depending on how you cycle. Please edit your question so it asks about an actual problem you face.

Comment: @Criggie positive *real numbers*

Comment: @sleske More information has been added.

Comment: Even after edits there is still no possible answer to the question as written. I think you need to ask what might be possible on *your* commute (whatever distance that is) to meet *your* goals specifically.

Comment: Target heart rate and power depend on your goals and your personal max heart rate and functional power thresholds respectively. Both are really dependent on the person. For example on my commute I typically target an average of 300-350 watts and mix in some high intensity intervals (e.g., Tabata) 2x a week in the summer so I have the speed  and acceleration for club A rides. All I care about is working on my 1 to 5 min power so I can launch attacks. Your interest may be hour long time trials which would necessitate a different schedule. Without know fitness goals it is hard to generalize.

Comment: I tried to grab a heart-rate graph for my commute, but the sensor dropped.  Have changed battery and will try again tomorrow.

Comment: @Rider_X's comment is one worthwhile approach. With very different goals (Audax/endurance in hilly country) I try to get up the (short) hills on my commute as fast as possible. I do have a few stretches where it's worth sprinting on the flat for a couple of minutes but my main goal commuting is to get there in one piece, and much of the time traffic limits maximum speed.

Comment: Let's say you did intervals. Do your rides to work need to be at zone 1 between interval sessions? Can zone 2 or higher all the way be used to shorten commute times? If so, what's the highest training zone that can be used to used and not be overtrained? Should intervals be done when going to work or going home?

Comment: What length commute do you have, and how much elevation change does it involve?

Comment: @Han-Lin - For faster commute times in general I would look up exercises to increase your FTP (Training Peaks has some good examples).  To start with I would keep it to 2 sessions in a week and see how you do.  Take at minimum one easy day between and see how you recover.  Zone 2, low zone 3 should be sufficient, but depends on how well you know your zones (i.e., 220 - age is a poor measure), your age and fitness.  Depending on how things are going you could try throwing in a sprint interval exercise.  If you have a short commute, then FTP training will need to be done away from commuting.

Comment: Zero for now. If there's a distance, I would expect at least 50m of elevation changes. In the future, it may be 20 min to an hour or longer.

Comment: I still don't see an answerable question here -- this looks more like a survey, if anything.

Answer (score 6):

I would claim, without data so just thinking about my experience with the world, that most commuters are not targeting heart rate or power, they are just trying to get to work.  Some want to get there as fast as they are (reasonably) capable of and some are wanting to get there at a reasonable pace that does not require a shower. Many just want to get there.  There must be some who try to combine sophisticated training with commuting, but those are few.

Comment: I reckon there are quite a few who chuck in some *un*sophisticated training (e.g. take certain opportunities to sprint, push the cadence, etc.) but on the whole you're right.